# How to avoid client caches (Chrome) on django react app?

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, caching, django-templates

I have a django-react app that is serving out of Heroku. I use webpack to build static files, which I serve out of a Django app called frontend. Django static files serving adds a hash to the webpack generated files for cache breaking on new releases.

To illustrate, here is the index.html that is served for my site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.e62ca627caf.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/frontend/css/index.e861872e9ba7b.css"/>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.a22d2aecab21fe.json" />

</head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/frontend/js/index.a39c981a0accf.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Cache-Control` for `index.html` is set to `max-age=0`. I thought this setup would be good enough for breaking client caches when I release a new frontend version of my site (since index.*.js would have a new hash). However, I observed that some of my clients had stale versions up to two weeks ago even with this setup (using Chrome on Windows). How is this possible? Am I missing something to break client caches for new frontend releases?

Comment: Also, I am just using raw heroku. I don't have a CDN in front of my servers